# LED driver - current monitoring AC or DC side with Arduino

Tags: arduino, current-measurement, led-driver

I have 2 LED strips connected in parallel to the same LED driver (driver is constant current + constant voltage). I have got an Arduino controlling a relay module that switches the lights on or off (on the ac side of the driver - INPUT).I know ideally it should be each strip with its driver, but I can't change that at the moment.

I want to monitor this system with a current transformer (current sensor) but I don't know which side should I monitor. If one of the modules switches off or gets damaged will the output of the driver stay constant even though the load has changed (I'm assuming it does, might be wrong????). What about the supply to the driver? If one of the modules goes off will the driver pull a smaller current from the mains?

These are the sensors I was thinking of using or something similar:

[AC side](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1486.html)

[DC side](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1164#technical-details)

Thank you.

Comment: think about what you are asking ... you have a constant current supply, why would you monitor the output current ... if some LEDs fail, then the current output of the power supply does not change ... but, the voltage output of the power supply will change to keep the current the same

Comment: Agreed @ jsotola .. .@Andrei_M  supply cannot be (constant current + constant voltage) at the same time.. if operating in voltage control mode  (open-circuit failure) won't cause any change in behavior ...and ...if operating in current control mode  (short-circuit failure) won't cause any change in behavior ... Supply of the driver will be okay if supply it has failure protection... how much current driver will pull depends on the short/open circuit failure mode and it's equivalent circuit at that time

Comment: @rahulb thank you for clarification. Correct me if I'm wrong but based on your answer there no way I could check for faults ? Because no matter the fault the driver will try and keep current the same. I'm using the following driver: HLG-480H-48A. What about a voltage divider to the arduino ? Will that work?